org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start()
For infinispan version: 9.2.1.Final
'org.infinispan', name: 'infinispan-core', version: '9.2.1.Final'

and Java 8, I am getting the following error:
1) Error injecting constructor, org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start() on object of type PersistenceManagerImpl
  at com.raster.cache.TileCacheImpl.<init>(TileCacheImpl.scala:37)
  at com.raster.cache.TileCacheImpl.class(TileCacheImpl.scala:35)
  while locating com.raster.cache.TileCacheImpl
  while locating com.raster.cache.TileCache
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start() on object of type PersistenceManagerImpl

The above error started appearing up randomly without any changes upon redeploying a build. Can anyone help or hint something to sort this issue?

can you share the source code?
Also is there a special reason for using the old infinispan version?
